# Elixir: use `:into` for range generator (numbers)

Tags: elixir

Let's see the following expression in Elixir:

```elixir
iex> for n <- 1..30, rem(n, 3) == 0, do: n * 10
[30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300]
```

I tried using [`:into` optional](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#the-into-option) to sum them up, but it failed:

```elixir
# expect to get `1650` from `[30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300]`
iex> for n <- 1..30, rem(n, 3) == 0, into: 0, do: n * 10
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Collectable not implemented for 0
    (elixir) lib/collectable.ex:1: Collectable.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/collectable.ex:46: Collectable.into/1
```

Is it possible to use `:into` to combine the results from enumerated number values?

If yes, how?

Comment: It rather sounds like you would need [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2), to, well, _reduce_ list of integers into one integer...

Comment: Consider: `1..30 |> Enum.filter(fn n -> rem(n, 3) == 0 end) |> Enum.reduce(0, fn n, acc -> acc + n * 10 end)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `into` can only be used to collect into a [`Collectable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Collectable.html) type. Integers are not `Collectable`.

You can use `Enum.sum/1` here, but you probably already knew that:

```
iex(1)> Enum.sum(for n <- 1..30, rem(n, 3) == 0, do: n * 10)
1650
```

You can use `Enum.reduce/3` here though, if your goal is to not create an intermediate list:

```
Enum.reduce(1..30, 0, fn n, acc -> if(rem(n, 3) == 0, do: acc + n * 10, else: acc) end)
1650
```

Edit: Integers can be made to implement `Collectable` with the behavior being addition, but I don't recommend it because (1) this implementation will be global and (2) there's no obvious way to "collect" into an integer, you could just as well use multiplication instead of addition. Just for learning purposes though, here's how you would implement `Collectable` for integers with addition behavior:

```
defimpl Collectable, for: Integer do
  def into(acc) do
    {acc, fn
      acc, {:cont, x} -> acc + x
      acc, _ -> acc
    end}
  end
end

IO.inspect for n <- 1..30, rem(n, 3) == 0, into: 0, do: n * 10
```

Output:

```
1650
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. It that possible to make Integer support `Collectable`?

Comment: It would, but there's more than one implementation that makes sense - it could be a sum, a product or an average - just to start.

Comment: @Dogbert, awesome! Can I use other keyword instead of `:into`? For example, `:sum`: `for n <- 1..30, rem(n, 3) == 0, sum: 0, do: n * 10`

Comment: @李岡諭 You cannot extend the builtin `for` like that. You can write your own macro and call that though.

Answer (score 1):

As Dogbert wrote integers doesn't implement Collectable protocols.
When you have a task: "transform list into number", think about `Enum.reduce`.

```
a = for n <- 1..30, rem(n, 3) == 0, do: n * 10
Enum.reduce a, 0, &Kernel.+/2
> 1650
```